# How to prevent same bundle from getting regenerated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

The problem we are running into is that we've defined two bundles containing .less files, and  we'd like to use one bundle at one time, or the other, based on some arbitrary condition (Imagine that the bundles are nearly identical, but might have minor cosmetic differences).

Suppose we have the following in _layout.cshtml:

```
    @{
        var bundleName="~/Content/LessBundle";
        if (DateTime.Now.Minute % 2 == 1)
        {
            bundleName="~/Content/LessBundle_v2";
        }
        @Styles.Render(bundleName);
    }
```

The unexpected behavior we are seeing in Fiddler is that with the above code, every time a page is refreshed in the browser, A GET request occurs and returns a 200, but the same bundle ID is generated.

To further demonstrate, here is what we are seeing in Fiddler output (oldest to newest requests)

```
12:01:10:
GET /blah/LessBundle?v=8wWviX6PRM-m1BrNdFSTtQQQo_2xtnt6d4aNKYp9p_Y1 HTTP/1.1 (200 return code)
12:01:20:
GET /blah/LessBundle?v=8wWviX6PRM-m1BrNdFSTtQQQo_2xtnt6d4aNKYp9p_Y1 HTTP/1.1 (200 return code) ***********should be 304
12:02:05
GET /blah/LessBundle?v=9yWviXPRM-k1BrNdFSTtQQQo_2dddddd4aNKYp9p_B1 HTTP/1.1 (200 return code) OK, new bundle should have been returned
12:02:35
GET /blah/LessBundle?v=9yWviXPRM-k1BrNdFSTtQQQo_2dddddd4aNKYp9p_B1 HTTP/1.1 (200 return code) ***********should be 304
```

What we are trying to figure out is how to make the change so that if the bundle hasn't changed, we don't regenerate it and send the whole payload on every request

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dominique

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the problem was that I was hitting ctrl-f5 instead of f5 in chrome. This forces instead a cache refresh instead of doing a regular refresh.

When I refresh via f5, everything is fine.

No problems, move along :)